# How to get the same behavior like xsl:value-of select in an onclick hyperlink attribute?

Tags: xslt

I've got an xsl issue, this is the situation:

```
 <td onclick="location.href='/vakman/default.asp?name='" style="cursor:pointer" valign="top" height="100%">
```

After `default.asp?name='` I need this value: `<xsl:value-of select="veld[5]" />`

Can someone help me with the right notation?

### UPDATE

Here's some more of the code I use:

```
<table border="0" align="right" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <xsl:for-each select="//regels/item">
        <xsl:variable name="coor" select="veld[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="coor1" select="veld[2]" />
        <xsl:variable name="naam" select="veld[5]"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="xsl:getKop()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <td onclick="location.href='/vakman/default.asp?naam='" style="cursor:pointer" valign="top" height="100%">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" class="toppersTable" width="250px" height="75px">
                <tr><td>
                    <b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="xsl:showOms(string(veld[5]))" /> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="xsl:showOms(string(veld[6]))" /></b><br />
                    <xsl:value-of select="xsl:showOms(string(veld[8]))" /><br />
                    <xsl:value-of select="xsl:showOms(string(veld[9]))" />  
                    <xsl:value-of select="xsl:showOms(string(veld[10]))" /><br />
                    <xsl:value-of select="xsl:showOms(string(veld[11]))" />
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <xsl:value-of select="xsl:getBottom()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$coor" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$coor1" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you use Jquery? (if you're running this in a browser)? The selectors make it very easy to implement.

Comment: Is the <td onclick> part of the output of your XSLT or the input?

Comment: Can you help me with the right notation? I'm new with XSL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Freek: have you checked my answer? I think it would fix your problem.

Comment: @Freek: if you have additional questions, please ask them by clicking "add comment", don't try to alter the answer itself (PS: welcome at SO!).

Comment: @abel Thanks! SO is very useful for rookies like me!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a better, shorter and much more readable solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<td onclick="location.href='/vakman/default.asp?name={veld[5]}'" 
style="cursor:pointer" valign="top" height="100%">
```

**Explanation**:  The use of AVT (Attribute Value Templates) is recommended whenever the name of the attribute is statically known. It results in shorter and more readable code.

Comment: +1: agreed, this is easier. Will you be at XMLPraque this weekend?

Comment: @Dimitre: +1: didn't know this shortcut. Which XSL version supports it?

Comment: @dimitre Novatchev Thanks a lot! I thought to difficult!

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks. I had already checked it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), but i forgot to remove the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`xsl:attribute` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_attribute.asp). you'll end up with something like this:

```
<td style="cursor:pointer" valign="top" height="100%">
   <xsl:attribute name="onclick">location.href='/vakman/default.asp?name=<xsl:value-of select="veld[5]" />'</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot. But when I click on the table, nothing happend. I've edited the original question and put some more script in the question

Comment: @Freek: XSLT doesn't create correct HTML or JavaScript code. Check your output with, for instance, FireBug.